# Difference between the mean of individual score vs mean score across all users

Tags: statistics, average, mean

I have a table where click to open rate (CTO) is calculated for individual (open and click count is collected from users)

| user | open count | click count | CTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 | 0.1 |
| B | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 4 | 1 | 0.25 |

now, if I calculate the average CTO, there are two ways:

1. (0.1+0+0.25)/3 = 0.1167
2. (1+0+1)/(10+5+4) = 0.1053

Option 1 gives me the average of individual CTO; option 2 gives me the average CTO overall?

I do not quite understand the difference between these two: is there an official name for option 1 and 2? And is making sense to compare these two numbers (0.1167 vs 0.1053)?

Any related stats reading would be appreciated as well.
Thank you.